# How do I embedd a graph in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, charts

I'm looking to graph basic database data in a X Y axis graph.

I would like a solution where the users do not need to download any extra plug-ins (i.e. Silverlight).

Looking for the most efficient/fastest solution where the chart is embedded into the page as a graph, instead of just looking at the table data.

Is there a built-in solution for this in asp.net 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option would be to use the [Microsoft Charting Controls for ASP.Net](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) which you add to your asp.net application. It can then be used to create various different kinds of charts with your data and the result could be an image to the client (jpg, png etc). Your users wouldn't require any add-ons etc

Comment: thank you, that looks like what I am looking for. What do you think of this solution compared to the google charts?

Comment: I haven't used the google charts, and they do look good. It does put a dependency on the users accessing google etc but that's not likely too much of a problem...It also takes the load off your server producing the image as well...Still the MS Charts are designed for use in asp.net applications. The Google option may pose a problem on an intranet perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest http://code.google.com/apis/chart/, it's Google's Charting API. They are plugin-free, you just link to an image and Google draws the thing for you dynamically.

Comment: Nice, I have seen these before. What do you think the advantages are with these over using MS Charting controls recommended by 'davisleeps' ? Thank you.

Comment: Offloading work to other sites is always a plus. You save bandwidth for one thing. Plus Google is a well known professional team of programmers, I'm sure their API is top notch. On the other hand, the Google Chart API is only accesible through its address, whereas the asp.net control has an actual programming interface.